# Java "-cp" option, compile time or runtime?

Tags: java, classpath

I see people saying there are different types of classpaths. for example compile time classpath and runtime classpath.

I guess the `"-cp"` or `"-classpath"` option when used with `javac` is compile time classpath.

and when used with `java` command it should be the runtime classpath. Am I correct?

Can these two classpaths be completely different?

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is basically yes :p

Comment: @fge - Don't you think the term *build-path* would be better than *compile-time classpath*?

Comment: yes i do. that's a good way to name it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java` and `javac` commands accepts either `-cp` or `-classpath` ... meaning the same thing.

Once upon a time, `javac` accepted only `-classpath`.

---

> Can these two classpaths [used by java and javac] be completely different?

They can be.  However, if you compile with one version of an API and run with a different one, you can potentially run into "binary compatibility" problems that lead to runtime errors.

It is therefore *advisable* to use the same (or equivalent) classpaths at compile time and runtime.

---

> Why the same content two times?

Because the content (the classpath) doesn't get compiled into the code.

A deeper answer is that a Java program typically consists of components (e.g. libraries) that are compiled independently and then brought together when you run the application.  Each of the component builds requires a different classpath ... according to its dependencies.  And when you put all of the pieces together a different again classpath may be required.  Hence the need to be able to specify the classpath differently at compile and runtime.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess the "-cp" or "-classpath" option when used with javac is compile time classpath.

Exactly!

> Can these two classpaths be completely different?

It's preferable these two be the same.

Otherwise, if you can get a [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) error, if some class was existing at compile-time (and was actually used in your code), but was missing at Runtime.

The classpaths **can** be different only when at compile-time you add classes to the classpath, which are not used in your source. In this situation, you can skip adding these to the Runtime classpath.

However, I would advice you keep you classpath(s) clean of unneeded classes/libraries.

Comment: Do you mean if I specify a compile time jar to my app when compiling. I also need to specify the same path when running the app too?

Comment: 1) javac -cp /some/path MyCLass.java     2)  java -cp /some/path MyClass

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. And avoid adding unused classes to the classpath. It doesn't affect performance or anything, it's just tedious to maintain.

Comment: in application servers, compile-time classpath differs from runtime classpath?

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the "-cp" or "-classpath" option when used with javac is
>   compile time classpath.

Yes that is true.

From the [java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> The JDK tools java, jdb, javac, and javah have a -classpath option
>   which replaces the path or paths specified by the CLASSPATH
>   environment variable while the tool runs. This is the recommended
>   option for changing class path settings, because each application can
>   have the class path it needs without interfering with any other
>   application.
>
> **The runtime tool java has a -cp option, as well. This option is an
>   abbreviation for -classpath.**
>
> For very special cases, both java and javac have options that let you
>   change the path they use to find their own class libraries. The vast
>   majority of users will never to need to use those options, however.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "-cp" or "-classpath" option when used with javac is compile time classpath.

`yes`

Can these two classpaths be completely different?

`they should be same`

> for any
>   given class, the `java` virtual machine will need to find exactly the same supporting
>   classes that the `javac` compiler needed to find at compilation time.In other words,
>   if `javac` needed access to `java.util.HashMap` then the `java` command will need
>   to find `java.util.HashMap` as well.